# Data importing issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i'm getting the data here in this way:

```
const handleSearch = async () => {
        if (search) {
            const { data } = await getCropDetails(search);
            const cropsData = data.crops;
        }
    }
```

I want to use this data in this file. How can i do it? Is there any way we can do it?

I just want the data in the file below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import { Stack, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


function SearchCard({ data }) {
    return (
        <Stack alignItems='center' justifyContent='center'>
            <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 300 }}>
                <CardMedia
                    style={{
                        height: "300px",
                    }}
                    component="img"
                    image="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
                    alt="crops"
                />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                        {/* {data.crops[0].name} */}
                        Banana
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum at id hic nihil eligendi asperiores placeat nostrum quis voluptatibus itaque enim, recusandae aspernatur quisquam odio nobis, impedit modi. Suscipit, eos.
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <Stack alignItems='center'>
                    <Link to='/details' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Link>
                </Stack>
            </Card>
        </Stack>
    );
}

export default SearchCard
```

Comment: can't you just import the function, invoke it where you need it and get its return value (and assign it to a state variable if needed)?

Answer (score 0):

If you tring to pass the `cropsData` from the `handleSearch` function to the `SearchCard` component, what you can do its to modify the `SearchCard` component to accept `cropsData` as a prop and use it to render the search results.

Try this :

app component:

```
function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [cropsData, setCropsData] = useState([]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    if (search) {
      const { data } = await getCropDetails(search);
      setCropsData(data.crops);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={search} onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>Search</button>

      <div>
        {cropsData.map((crop) => (
          <SearchCard key={crop.id} data={crop} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

SearchCard component:

```
function SearchCard({ data }) {
  return (
    <Stack alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 300 }}>
        <CardMedia
          style={{
            height: "300px",
          }}
          component="img"
          image={data.image}
          alt={data.name}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            {data.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            {data.description}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <Stack alignItems="center">
          <Link to="/details" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <CardActions>
              <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Link>
        </Stack>
      </Card>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```